# Magento 2.3.x installed in windows 10 using XAMPP backend and frontend not load properly

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, xampp, windows10

I am installed Magento 2.3.x in windows 10 using XAMPP backend and frontend not load properly.

I was installed much time and also I have run all Magento command but did not get any success.

[image]

[image]

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to deploy theme. Run the following command.

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

After doing this, if you get a blank page then restart xampp. It will work.

Comment: I have already tried this not getting any success.

Comment: are you using windows system ?

Comment: Yes I am using windows 10

Comment: Windows is not compatible to magento 2. Add these line of code in you index.php file which is on root to see the error in detail. 

ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ERROR);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);

register_shutdown_function("fatal_handler");
function fatal_handler() {
    $error = error_get_last();
    echo("<pre>");
    print_r($error);
}

Comment: which line I will add in index.php?

Comment: for windows system, open file /vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template/File/Validator.php in magento install dir , find

$realPath = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path);

replace with :

$realPath = str_replace('\\', '/', $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97832/discussion-between-sweety-masmiya-and-surendra-mishra).